# Why are these Twitter Bootstrap navbar classes conflicting?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am using Bootstrap 3 that has not long been released. They changed the markup a bit in comparison to Bootstrap 2.xx.
Previously I asked the community on how I would center the buttons/links inside of a Boostrap navbar, and I was told that bootstrap offers a new class `nav-justified`. And when applied to a navbar it works brilliantly.

However my issue is that when I apply that it removes the style of a default the default look of bootstraps navbars. Sure it wouldn't be too hard to correct that with CSS but I'm wondering as to why just a center CSS class would remove the style of this?
Check out my Jsfiddle to get a more clearer view on what I mean

> http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6582/

Comment: Bootstrap 3 hasn't `not long been released`, _it hasn't been released at all yet_. You're using a release candidate which may still have bugs in it, which might be why you're seeing problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is still in RC1. 
That means it's still on development and released for developers to be tested,you shouldn't download it unless you are a developer and a people who will help find bugs. 
So what you need at the first is Bootstrap 2.3.2 because Bootstrap 3 was released at RC1 which means t's still on development and have alot of bugs...
I already try bootstrap 3 there was alot of bugs i guess you shouldn't use Bootstrap 3 First until it's completely released.